# php Конвертация ресурса GD в ImageMagick и обратно

Tags: php, gd, imagemagick

Есть код написанный с использованием GD для обработки изображений.
Проблема в том, что возможностей GD не хватает, поэтому хочется дополнительно использовать еще и ImageMagick, но не переписывать под него весь код.

Вся беда в том что что эти библиотеки используют разные ресурсы изображений.
Т.е., в GD он получается так:

```
$image = @imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
```

А в ImageMagick так:

```
$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');
```

И они не совместимы.

Есть ли функция для конвертации ресурсов этих двух библиотек?

Можно конечно конвертировать через промежуточный файл, но мне не нравится такой вариант

Comment: другого варианта и не будет. можете не в файл писать, а как нибудь в поток, чтобы не оперировать с файловой системой. Если они конечно умеют потом из потока загрузить

Comment: Интересная задачка. Стало интересно, есть ли у нее хоть какие то варианты, кроме как через файл. Известных мне - нет. Хотя и с той и с другой библиотеками я работаю часто. (Предпочитаю GD из-за его повсеместности) Гуглил, искал... что либо по Вашей теме... Увы.